# Jenkins post build step is delayed for a couple of minutes

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins job, that gets't delayed before executing postbuild action.

Any ideas what to check or how to proceed? 150 seconds of wasted time is a little bit too much.

Jenkins console output looks like this (see the time difference between first and second line):

```
14:06:01 [EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
14:08:37 Performing Post build task...
14:08:37 Logical operation result is FALSE
14:08:37 Skipping script  : echo Testing time
```

Job configuration: 
Build section

Inject environment variables (last task in this section)
Post-build Actions
 - Post build task (first task with script: echo Testing time)

Comment: Do You use Declarative Pipeline or something else? I need more info :)

Comment: A sample of code would be handy as well if possible. Doesn't need identical, you should strip any sensitive data if you're happy to provide a sample.